# How to convert a Python file encrypted with pyarmor into an exe file

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, request, pyarmor

I have a simple Python file whose content is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

i want encrypt this code using pyarmor then convert the file encrypted to exe file ..

I tried to encrypt the file and then use auto-py-to-exe to convert it into an exe file but the script is not working .. !!

Well I tried using pyinstaller but same problem.

What is the appropriate way to encode the source code and then convert it to an exe file?

i am using python 3.8...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pyarmor pack -e " --onefile" test.py